# java multithreading learning sources

Tags: java, multithreading

please let me know a java multithread application which i can refer ( source ) and
debug to understand how multithreading actually works in java ?

Comment: Just remember these simple rules: Don't share mutable state across threads, only one thread may "own" an immutable object, and use existing concurrency-aware objects. While these are just guidelines, they are fairly good ones for a number of concurrency-related situations and violating them may lead to hours of headaches.

Comment: Giving someone new to concurrency those rules and wishing them good luck is like giving someone a gun and sending them to Iraq with no further training.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official Sun [Java tutorial on concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is probably a good place to start.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Sun has a [decent tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).  But in all honestly, multithreaded programming is exremely difficult.  There is a well regarded book, [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).  If you really want to learn how to take advantage of multiple cores, look into [clojure](http://clojure.org/) or [scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this search](http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=Thread&search.x=0&search.y=0&la=Java&li=*&scope=), perhaps refined a bit, might help you in your quest... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start with oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html), which provides excellent source of information.

Few more useful links:

[jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html) tutorial

[howtodoinjava](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-concurrency-tutorial/) tutorial

[dzone](https://dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency) tutorial